# Using a variable as JQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown/select menu that shows and hides various divs based on what the user has selected. Within each div there is another dropdown/select menu that I would like to also trigger an action on change.

As this div is given an ID dynamically I am struggling to figure out how to select the required dropdown/select menu.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#category").change(function(){
        var category = $("#category").val();
        var box = $('#'+ category);
        $('.class-name').hide();
        box.show();
    }) ;

    var category = $("#category").val();
    var selector = 'selector_'+category;

    $("#"+selector).change(function(){
        alert('Do something');
    });
});
```

And some simplified HTML:

```
<select id='category'>
    <option value='0'>1</option>
    <option value='1'>2</option>
    <option value='2'>3</option>
</select>

<div class='box class-name' id='1'>
    <select id='selector_1'>
        <option value='1'>One</option>
        <option value='2'>Two</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class='box class-name' id='2'>
    <select id='selector_2'>
        <option value='1'>One</option>
        <option value='2'>Two</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class='box class-name' id='3'>
    <select id='selector_3'>
        <option value='1'>One</option>
        <option value='2'>Two</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The divs show and hide as desired, but I can't for the life of me get the alert('Do Something'); to trigger which I assume is a problem with how I am trying to select the dropdown/select menu.

All help much appreciated!

Cheers, DB.

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/phbd67b1/) is this what you want

Comment: Have you considered `$('.class-name:visible').change(function(){        alert('Do something');});` ? Tell us more about the second part that's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need chain the changes. The way you made it, the code runs all at once, meaning:

1. When document ready, do:
2. Set onChange in the #category element
3. Find category current value (right now, none is selected, so value is undefined)
4. Set selector to "selector_" + undefined
5. Find element with id selector, since there's no element with this id, no change is defined.

Try this, instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var categoryField = $("#category");
    categoryField.change(function() {
        var category = categoryField.val();
        var box = $('#'+ category);
        $('.class-name').hide();
        box.show();

        var selector = 'selector_'+category;

        $("#"+selector).change(function() {
            alert('Do something');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I've accepted this answer as it remains closest to my original code and explains why my original code was not working - I needed to "chain the changes"! This has helped me achieve what I want but also helped me learn. Thanks to all the other answers also!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. If the inside instructions of the selector "change" are always the same, there are better ways to do it, because this way is always setting the same change on an input, even if it has previously been set.

Answer (score 0):

```
var category = $("#category").val();
```

Category is empty on page loaded.

Simple solution:

```
$(".box select").change(function(){
    alert('Do something');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked, it's working

```
$("#category").change(function(){    
    var category = $("#category").val();
    var box = $('#'+ category);        
    $('.class-name').hide();
    box.show();
    var s = $(box).find('select');        
    $(s).bind("change", function() { 
       alert("Do something"); 
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Within each div there is another dropdown/select menu that I would
>   like to also trigger an action on change.

It seems you are looking to trigger event when there is a change in the dropdowns wrapped by the div

If it is so you can use jquery wild card selector

In your case all those `select` elements have same prefix id.

So $("[id^=selector_]") will response to to any select box which have such string as prefix

```
 $("[id^=selector_").change(function(event){
      $("#demoUp").text($(this).context.value);
    });
```

Check this [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/maumozds/). The placeholder will be updated by the value of selectd option

Answer (score 0):

To point you have change the `id` on document page ,use below

```
$(document).on("change",$("#"+selector),function(){
        alert('Do something');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#category").change(function(){
        var category = $(this).val();
        $('.class-name').hide();
        $('#'+ category).show();

        $("#selector_"+category).change(function(){
            alert('Do something');
        });
    }) ;

});
```